# I want to use gzip compression in Apache

Tags: apache, gzip

I want to enable gzip compression for acethehimalaya.com. Can anybody please tell me what is the best way of achieving compression in an Apache Webserver?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to look into `mod_deflate` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html)

Depending on the operating system, but on most Linux-based systems you can do the following:

1. edit the configuration file httpd.conf or similar)
2. if you have a `VirtualHost` container, add this: `SetOutputFilter DEFLATE`
3. you can also set directory-specific compression:

   `<Directory "/path/to/website">`

   `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html`

   `</Directory>`

On the other hand, and probably a more efficient thing, is to use Google's `mod_pagespeed` [(link)](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/download). In summary, install one of the binaries on the right-side of the page. This will automatically perform updates for you when you run updates on the [server?]. You can compile it yourself as well.

The benefits of `mod_pagespeed` are that it compresses AND caches your content for you. Thereby reducing CPU usage and bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to manage Gzip compression in Apache is to add these lines in your [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html):

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

It works well for my website.

Comment: I tried the .htaccess entry but it dint work :(

Comment: Too bad because it works for me.